# Queueing process firestore database

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

On my front-end I have simply a button. When the user clicks on this button a HTTP request send to server to update an entry (+1 on each click on button).

But we know, firestore database or another DBMS if thousands of users clicks on same time on button what happen ? crash ? or something else, but we would not this behavior

I try to find a solution with firestore to queueing all process when user click on button for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to increment a value in the database is by using Firestore's `increment()` operation, document in [incrementing a numeric value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value).

Aside from that, Firestore has a [soft limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#soft_limits) of about 1 write per document per second. If you consistently need to write to a single document more than that, consider using an alternate strategy like a [distributed counter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters), which spreads the writes over a number of documents.

In general this type of sharding the writes will be the solution for most write limits. You can then either have the clients read back multiple documents (as the distributed counter above does), or you can have a backend process that updates a central location, but then has a mechanism to handle back pressure (for example through PubSub or Cloud Tasks).

Comment: For the POC of my project the distrubuted counter seem to be a good alternative before I learn pub/sub 
Thanks !